# Qt QGraphicsScene::drawItems subsitute?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsscene

For `QGraphicsScene::drawItems` the reference says:

> Reimplement this function to provide custom painting of all items for the scene; gaining complete control over how each item is drawn.

But this function is marked as obsolete.
Is there any new equivalent method?

Answer (score 1):

`QGraphicsView::paintEvent()` now calls

```
d->scene->d_func()->drawItems()
```

which means the method is part of class `QGraphicsScenePrivate` which you cannot override afaik.

If you need to change the way your items are drawn, first try to think of another way (i.e. a solution which does not require stepping into the `drawItems()` method). If you can't find any solution like that, your only chance is reactivating the pre-4.6-behaviour by setting

```
QGraphicsView::setOptimizationFlag( QGraphicsView::IndirectPainting )
```

Comment: What I'm looking are two things:
1.- A Way to know the progress of painting
2.- A way to stop the process of painting 
And ... I would like to use a future deleted method .... 
Thanks Tim